# Java Spring Security: 401 Unauthorized for token OAuth2 end point

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a fairly basic setup in my Spring Boot project. I'm trying to set up OAuth2 to protect my API but I'm running into issues with my `/oauth/token` end point. Making either a POST or GET request to my `/oauth/token` end point results in the following response (With a `401 Unauthorized` status code):

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-09-17T16:46:59.961+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/oauth/token"
}
```

This is my Authorization server configuration.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.UserApprovalHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("client_id")
                .secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(600)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                .userApprovalHandler(this.userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

This is my resource server configuration. Nothing significant yet:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;

public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(this.tokenStore);
    }
}
```

And finally my standard web security configuration:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.ApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.UserApprovalHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
        security.csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(this.clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(this.clientDetailsService);

        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);

        return store;
    }
}
```

I've messed around quite a bit with different matcher patterns to see if I can get it working but I haven't had any luck. I'm running this in a root context and servlet path on `http://localhost:8080`.

I can confirm that the end point is mapped in the output when Spring Boot fires up and trying to hit a slightly different end point results in an expected 404.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't hitting the end point correctly. I was sending all of my data, client credentials included, via HTTP POST.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
...
client_id=client_id&secret=secret&scope=read&grant_type=password&username=user&password=password
```

I needed to use HTTP Basic Auth to send my client credentials rather than POSTing them:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50X2lkOnNlY3JldA==
...
scope=read&grant_type=password&username=user&password=password
```

Comment: how can i send a HTTP Basic Auth with postman ?

Comment: "Authorization" tab, choose "Basic Auth" from the "TYPE" dropdown, enter username/password: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#basic-auth

Comment: i send this post request "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user&password=user" with authorization header param and and basic auth from the "Authorization" tab ?

Answer (score 7):

try changing your password encoder from your `AuthorizationServerConfig` class with this simple encoder(it doesn't encrypt passwords).because you don't save your client secret in InMemory storage with encryption.

```
private PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
    return new PasswordEncoder() {
        public String encode (CharSequence charSequence) {
            return charSequence.toString();
        }
        public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've given it a shot but I'm still seeing the same problem.

Comment: It turns out that although this wasn't my actual issue at the time, your answer did help me after I figured my issue out since I was getting errors about BCrypt, so thanks for that.