# Java Spring Security OAuth2: Accept client credentials via POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a fairly basic Spring Boot setup and I have installed Spring Security and I have managed to successfully set up OAuth2 to protect my API.

I had some trouble a few days back and [asked (and answered) a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52375676/2244675) with regards to hitting my `/oauth/token` end point. I soon figured out that the problem was that I was trying to send my client credentials in the body of my `POST` request but the token end point is configured in Spring Security to accept the client credentials (`client_id` and `secret`) via HTTP Basic Auth instead.

Most of my experience with consuming OAuth2 APIs has involved sending client credentials in the body of the `POST` request and I was wondering if it was possible to configure Spring Security to function in the same way?

I've tried a few different things with no success, like setting the following configuration option, but I feel like that might only be used when configuring an OAuth2 client:

```
security.oauth2.client.clientAuthenticationScheme=form
```

This is my Authorization server configuration.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.UserApprovalHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("client_id")
                .secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(600)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                .userApprovalHandler(this.userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check about `allowFormAuthenticationForClients`.

Comment: @chrylis Me neither, I can't understand why. I didn't assume or direct the question at you though, in case you felt like I did. If you'd like to post an answer, I'll happily accept it. If not I'll post one myself an accept that one for future visitors.

Comment: You write it up; I'm feeling too lazy to explain thoroughly. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @chrylis in the comments, the trick is to use the [`allowFormAuthenticationForClients`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configurers/AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.html#allowFormAuthenticationForClients()) method on `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer` when configuring the authorization server. In my case, I have this in my `AuthorizationServerConfig` class:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
    security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
            .passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder)
            .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
}
```

That will allow passing client credentials via standard parameters, such as in the body of the `POST` request (or in the query string), though Spring prefers using HTTP Basic Auth by joining the `client_id` and `secret` together with a colon (`<client_id>:<secret>`), base-64 encoding the result, prefixing it with `Basic` and passing that to the `Authorization` header, so you would end up with something like this:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l
```